# Как писать историю ejabberd в postgresql?

Tags: linux, postgresql, erlang

Стоит `ejabberd 2.1.11` из реп.
Для хранения истории в бд поставил:

```
{mod_archive_odbc, [{database_type, "pgsql"},
    {default_auto_save, true},
    {enforce_default_auto_save, true},
    {default_expire, infinity},
    {enforce_min_expire, 0},
    {enforce_max_expire, infinity},
    {replication_expire, 31536000},
    {session_duration, 1800},
    {wipeout_interval, 86400},
    {mod_archive_webview, []}]}
```

Проблема в том, что историю пишет следующим образом:

```
 id  | coll_id |         utc         | dir |     body      | name 
-----+---------+---------------------+-----+---------------+------
   1 |       1 | 2015-10-09 16:19:57 |   1 | test1         | 
   2 |       1 | 2015-10-09 16:19:57 |   0 | test1         | 
   3 |       1 | 2015-10-09 16:20:00 |   1 | test2         | 
   4 |       1 | 2015-10-09 16:20:00 |   0 | test2         | 
   5 |       2 | 2015-10-09 16:20:11 |   1 | test3         | 
   6 |       2 | 2015-10-09 16:20:11 |   0 | test3         | 
   7 |       3 | 2015-10-09 16:20:38 |   1 | test4         | 
   8 |       4 | 2015-10-09 16:20:38 |   0 | test4         |
```

а сама таблица диалогов с определением юзеров:
`archive_collections`
с такой структурой:

```
id
prev_id
next_id
us
with_user
with_server
with_resource
utc
change_by
change_utc
deleted
subject
thread
crypt
extra
```

Как сразу писать в одну таблицу всё?

Comment: Если не устраивает схема данных, используемая ejabberd, придётся написать свой модуль, который пишет данные по-вашему.

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

---

Если не устраивает схема данных, используемая *ejabberd*, придётся написать свой модуль, который пишет данные по-вашему.